# GlusterFS on FreeBSD 11.1 / Mount issue

Tags: mount, freebsd, glusterfs

I want to use GlusterFS as a distributed Filestorage on FreeBSD 11.1
Documentation is poor, so I followed some howtos on the net.
I could create the glusterfs volume, but I have trouble to mount it on an other clients machine. Here is what I did so far:

I have three hosts, all in the same subnet.

```
10.0.0.21 Webserver
10.0.0.31 gluster1
10.0.0.32 gluster2
```

I added the above entries in the /etc/hosts files on all of the three hosts.

I modified /etc/rc.conf on gluster1 and gluster2 with:

```
glusterd_enable="YES"
```

on gluster1 I did:

```
gluster peer probe gluster2
```

(succeeded)

each gluster1 and gluster2 has the following harddrives: /dev/da1

they are partitioned (BSD Label) and mounted on gluster1 and gluster2 as /datastore

"cat /etc/fstab" gives on both gluster1 and gluster2:

```
# Device        Mountpoint      FStype  Options Dump    Pass#
/dev/da0a       /               ufs     rw      1       1
/dev/da1a       /datastore      ufs     rw      2       2
```

I created the gluster volume1:

```
gluster volume create volume1 replica 2 transport tcp gluster1:/datastore gluster2:/datastore force
```

(I'm aware of the split brain risk, this is a simple test szenario)

I started the volume1 with:

```
gluster volume start volume1
```

A check of the volume1 with:

```
gluster volume info
```

gives me back:

```
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: a760c545-1cc9-47a4-bc9e-51f6180e4d7a
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gluster1:/datastore
Brick2: gluster2:/datastore
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
```

So far everything worked, and seems to be fine.

Now my trouble starts to mount and use this on the client / consumer machine (Webserver)

I read at several places that the glusterfs volume1 should be mountable with:

```
mount -t glusterfs gluster1:/volume1 /mnt
```

This gives me simple back the following error:

```
mount: gluster1:/volume1: Operation not supported by device
```

As I normally do before I ask "silly" questions, I googled a lot for this.
Played around with also installing glusterfs on the client (pkg install glusterfs), enabling it in the clients /etc/rc.conf, adding stuff for FUSE, but I could not bring it up to work. 
I feel quite annoyed, because I know it must be a very small thing I'm missing here!?

Can anyone shed some light into my issue?

EDIT:
I saw that the NFS seems not to be working:
Status of volume1 shows no listening TCP Port

```
gluster volume status volume1
```

shows:

```
Status of volume: volume1
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick gluster1:/datastore                   N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Brick gluster2:/datastore                   N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        N       55181
Self-heal Daemon on gluster2                N/A       N/A        N       30318

Task Status of Volume volume1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

So, I enabled NFS with this:

```
gluster volume set volume1 nfs.disable off
```

There was a warning of no longer using GlusterFS NFS, but instead to use  NFS-Ganesha. The warning I ignored for this test.

now I restarted the volume:

```
gluster volume stop volume1 
gluster volume start volume1
```

To check I did:

```
gluster volume info
```

which showed me now:

```
Volume Name: volume1
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: a760c545-1cc9-47a4-bc9e-51f6180e4d7a
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gluster1:/datastore
Brick2: gluster2:/datastore
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.disable: off
transport.address-family: inet
```

So the nfs.disable was set to off. NFS should be on now right?

But

```
gluster volume status volume1
```

still shows no NFS running:

```
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick gluster1:/datastore                   N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Brick gluster2:/datastore                   N/A       N/A        N       N/A
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        N       99115
NFS Server on gluster2                      N/A       N/A        N       N/A
Self-heal Daemon on gluster2                N/A       N/A        N       37075

Task Status of Volume volume1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks
```

Disturbing here is also (beside NFS Online is N), that both bricks seems to be not online too (Online indicated as N)?!??

So I'm really stuck and could use some help.

Comment: Another Google hour indicated that it could be related that the NFS is disabled on the gluster volume... I will follow up on this lead tomorrow...

Comment: Enabling glusterfs NFS did not help, read my edit section above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two years later, I finally figured out how to automount a glusterfs volume on Freebsd with FSTAB:

gluster1:/volume1       /mnt/glusterfs  fusefs          rw,acl,transport=tcp,_netdev,mountprog=/usr/local/sbin/mount_glusterfs,late             0       0

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is working:

```
/usr/local/sbin/mount_glusterfs gluster1:/volume1 /mnt
```

did the trick...

the client also need to have the net/glusterfs package installed, and the following statement in the /boot/loader.conf:

```
fuse_load="YES"
```

Cheers